# error when running VQE in Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit, vqe

I am running the code, which gets the ground state energy with different atomic distances of LiH. However, I encountered this error. The code is as follow

```
import numpy as np import pylab import copy
from qiskit import BasicAer
from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import NumPyMinimumEigensolver, VQE
from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers import SLSQP
from qiskit.chemistry.components.initial_states import HartreeFock
from qiskit.chemistry.components.variational_forms import UCCSD
from qiskit.chemistry.drivers import PySCFDriver
from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers import GroundStateEigensolver
from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers.minimum_eigensolver_factories import VQEUCCSDFactory
from qiskit.chemistry.transformations import (FermionicTransformation,
                                              FermionicTransformationType,
                                              FermionicQubitMappingType)
from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers.minimum_eigensolver_factories import VQEUCCSDFactory

molecule = 'H .0 .0 -{0}; Li .0 .0 {0}'
distances = np.arange(0.5,4.25,0.25)
vqe_energies = []
hf_energies = []
exact_energies = []
for i,d in enumerate(distances):
    print('step', i)
    #set up the experiment
    driver = PySCFDriver(molecule.format(d/2), basis='sto3g')
    fermionic_transformation = FermionicTransformation(
            transformation=FermionicTransformationType.FULL,
            qubit_mapping=FermionicQubitMappingType.JORDAN_WIGNER,
            two_qubit_reduction=False,
            freeze_core=False)
    qubit_op, aux_ops = fermionic_transformation.transform(driver)
    #VQE
    optimizer = SLSQP(maxiter=1000)
    initial_state = HartreeFock(fermionic_transformation.molecule_info['num_orbitals'],
                                        fermionic_transformation.molecule_info['num_particles'],
                                        qubit_mapping=fermionic_transformation.qubit_mapping,
                                        two_qubit_reduction=fermionic_transformation._two_qubit_reduction)
    #VQE
    vqe_solver = VQEUCCSDFactory(QuantumInstance(BasicAer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')),
                                 optimizer,
                                 initial_state)
    calc = GroundStateEigensolver(fermionic_transformation, vqe_solver)
    res = calc.solve(driver)
    print(res)
```

The traceback is here

```
  File "/home/ironmanaudi/research/VQE/VQE_tutorial/LiH_VQE.py", line 76, in <module>
    res = calc.solve(driver)
  File "/home/ironmanaudi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/chemistry/algorithms/ground_state_solvers/ground_state_eigensolver.py", line 102, in solve
    raw_mes_result = solver.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(operator, aux_operators)
  File "/home/ironmanaudi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/minimum_eigen_solvers/vqe.py", line 494, in compute_minimum_eigenvalue
    return self._run()
  File "/home/ironmanaudi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/minimum_eigen_solvers/vqe.py", line 429, in _run
    vqresult = self.find_minimum(initial_point=self.initial_point,
  File "/home/ironmanaudi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/vq_algorithm.py", line 172, in find_minimum
    if initial_point is not None and len(initial_point) != nparms:
TypeError: object of type 'HartreeFock' has no len()
```

When change the syntax of getting the result to

```
res = calc.solve(driver, aux_ops)
```

the error becomes

```
File "/home/ironmanaudi/research/VQE/VQE_tutorial/LiH_VQE.py", line 70, in <module>
    res = calc.solve(driver, aux_ops)
  File "/home/ironmanaudi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/chemistry/algorithms/ground_state_solvers/ground_state_eigensolver.py", line 90, in solve
    operator, aux_operators = self.transformation.transform(driver, aux_operators)
  File "/home/ironmanaudi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/chemistry/transformations/fermionic_transformation.py", line 152, in transform
    ops, aux_ops = self._do_transform(q_molecule, aux_operators)
  File "/home/ironmanaudi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/chemistry/transformations/fermionic_transformation.py", line 358, in _do_transform
    _add_aux_op(aux_op, name)
  File "/home/ironmanaudi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/chemistry/transformations/fermionic_transformation.py", line 289, in _add_aux_op
    aux_qop = FermionicTransformation._map_fermionic_operator_to_qubit(
  File "/home/ironmanaudi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/chemistry/transformations/fermionic_transformation.py", line 645, in _map_fermionic_operator_to_qubit
    qubit_op = fer_op.mapping(map_type=qubit_mapping, threshold=0.00000001)
AttributeError: 'SummedOp' object has no attribute 'mapping'
```

Can anybody tell me how to work this out?

Comment: It seems like the problem is with the initial_state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again here you are mixing some things. The `initial_state` in the `VQE` (that again you assign in the `initial_points`) is the starting values of the variational parameters. You have already specified the initial_state in the var_form. Then you should provide a solver in the calc and not run the solver manually. The code that works is here:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
import copy
from qiskit import BasicAer
from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import NumPyMinimumEigensolver, VQE
from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers import SLSQP
from qiskit.chemistry.components.initial_states import HartreeFock
from qiskit.chemistry.components.variational_forms import UCCSD
from qiskit.chemistry.drivers import PySCFDriver, UnitsType, Molecule
from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers import GroundStateEigensolver
from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers.minimum_eigensolver_factories import VQEUCCSDFactory
from qiskit.chemistry.transformations import (FermionicTransformation,
                                              FermionicTransformationType,
                                              FermionicQubitMappingType)
from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers.minimum_eigensolver_factories import VQEUCCSDFactory


distances = np.arange(0.5,4.25,0.25)
vqe_energies = []
hf_energies = []
exact_energies = []


for i,d in enumerate(distances):
    print('step', i)
    
    #set up the experiment
    molecule = Molecule(geometry=[['H', [0., 0., -1*(d/2)]],
                              ['H', [0., 0., (d/2)]]],
                     charge=0, multiplicity=1)
    driver = PySCFDriver(molecule = molecule, unit=UnitsType.ANGSTROM, basis='sto3g')
    fermionic_transformation = FermionicTransformation(
            transformation=FermionicTransformationType.FULL,
            qubit_mapping=FermionicQubitMappingType.JORDAN_WIGNER,
            two_qubit_reduction=False,
            freeze_core=False)
    
    qubit_op, aux_ops = fermionic_transformation.transform(driver)

    #VQE
    optimizer = SLSQP(maxiter=1)
    initial_state = HartreeFock(fermionic_transformation.molecule_info['num_orbitals'],
                                        fermionic_transformation.molecule_info['num_particles'],
                                        qubit_mapping=fermionic_transformation.qubit_mapping,
                                        two_qubit_reduction=fermionic_transformation._two_qubit_reduction)
    var_form = UCCSD(num_orbitals=fermionic_transformation.molecule_info['num_orbitals'],
                              num_particles=fermionic_transformation.molecule_info['num_particles'],
                              initial_state=initial_state,
                              qubit_mapping=fermionic_transformation.qubit_mapping,
                              two_qubit_reduction=fermionic_transformation._two_qubit_reduction)
    
    vqe_solver = VQE(qubit_op,var_form,optimizer, quantum_instance=QuantumInstance(BasicAer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')))
    
    calc = GroundStateEigensolver(fermionic_transformation, vqe_solver)
    
    res = calc.solve(driver)
    
    vqe_energies.append(res.computed_energies[0])
```

I also removed the double definition of the driver. Maybe consider the tutorials here: [Ground_state_solver](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/chemistry/03_ground_state_solvers.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks very much. The problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are mixing a couple of things here. The `VQEUCCSDFactory` uses the `HartreeFock` state as an initial_state by default. See also here [VQEUCCSDFactory](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/7775410f4dabf09ec9f933bf411ead434550accf/qiskit/chemistry/algorithms/ground_state_solvers/minimum_eigensolver_factories/vqe_uccsd_factory.py#L216-L217). The `initial_point` that you are specifying is the initial values of the variational parameters to start the optimization from.

One more point, seeing you snippet seems like you want to calculate a PES and you may want to take a look also to our BOPES Sampler tutorials here [BOPES tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/chemistry/05_Sampling_potential_energy_surfaces.ipynb)
.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is very helpful. I notice there are two ways to define a VQE algorithm. The first way is to use the 'VQEUCCSDFactory' object; the second way is to use the VQE object. I correct the code, but find there is still a problem with the second method, could you help me with it? I put the code of both methods in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is as the following

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
import copy
from qiskit import BasicAer
from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import NumPyMinimumEigensolver, VQE
from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers import SLSQP
from qiskit.chemistry.components.initial_states import HartreeFock
from qiskit.chemistry.components.variational_forms import UCCSD
from qiskit.chemistry.drivers import PySCFDriver, UnitsType, Molecule
from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers import GroundStateEigensolver
from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers.minimum_eigensolver_factories import VQEUCCSDFactory
from qiskit.chemistry.transformations import (FermionicTransformation,
                                              FermionicTransformationType,
                                              FermionicQubitMappingType)
from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers.minimum_eigensolver_factories import VQEUCCSDFactory


distances = np.arange(0.5,4.25,0.25)
vqe_energies = []
hf_energies = []
exact_energies = []


for i,d in enumerate(distances):
    print('step', i)
    
    #set up the experiment
    molecule = Molecule(geometry=[['H', [0., 0., -1*(d/2)]],
                              ['H', [0., 0., (d/2)]]],
                     charge=0, multiplicity=1)
    driver = PySCFDriver(molecule = molecule, unit=UnitsType.ANGSTROM, basis='sto3g')
    fermionic_transformation = FermionicTransformation(
            transformation=FermionicTransformationType.FULL,
            qubit_mapping=FermionicQubitMappingType.JORDAN_WIGNER,
            two_qubit_reduction=False,
            freeze_core=False)
    
    # qubit_op, aux_ops = fermionic_transformation.transform(driver)
    driver = PySCFDriver(molecule = molecule, unit=UnitsType.ANGSTROM, basis='sto3g')

    #VQE
    optimizer = SLSQP(maxiter=1000)
    vqe_solver = VQEUCCSDFactory(QuantumInstance(BasicAer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')), optimizer)
    
    calc = GroundStateEigensolver(fermionic_transformation, vqe_solver)
    res = calc.solve(driver)
    vqe_energies.append(res.computed_energies[0])
```

The second method :

````
import numpy as np
import pylab
import copy
from qiskit import BasicAer
from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import NumPyMinimumEigensolver, VQE
from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers import SLSQP
from qiskit.chemistry.components.initial_states import HartreeFock
from qiskit.chemistry.components.variational_forms import UCCSD
from qiskit.chemistry.drivers import PySCFDriver, UnitsType, Molecule
from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers import GroundStateEigensolver
from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers.minimum_eigensolver_factories import VQEUCCSDFactory
from qiskit.chemistry.transformations import (FermionicTransformation,
                                              FermionicTransformationType,
                                              FermionicQubitMappingType)
from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers.minimum_eigensolver_factories import VQEUCCSDFactory


distances = np.arange(0.5,4.25,0.25)
vqe_energies = []
hf_energies = []
exact_energies = []


for i,d in enumerate(distances):
    print('step', i)
    
    #set up the experiment
    molecule = Molecule(geometry=[['H', [0., 0., -1*(d/2)]],
                              ['H', [0., 0., (d/2)]]],
                     charge=0, multiplicity=1)
    driver = PySCFDriver(molecule = molecule, unit=UnitsType.ANGSTROM, basis='sto3g')
    fermionic_transformation = FermionicTransformation(
            transformation=FermionicTransformationType.FULL,
            qubit_mapping=FermionicQubitMappingType.JORDAN_WIGNER,
            two_qubit_reduction=False,
            freeze_core=False)
    
    qubit_op, aux_ops = fermionic_transformation.transform(driver)
    driver = PySCFDriver(molecule = molecule, unit=UnitsType.ANGSTROM, basis='sto3g')


    vqe_solver = VQEUCCSDFactory(QuantumInstance(BasicAer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')))
    
    #VQE
    optimizer = SLSQP(maxiter=1000)
    initial_state = HartreeFock(fermionic_transformation.molecule_info['num_orbitals'],
                                        fermionic_transformation.molecule_info['num_particles'],
                                        qubit_mapping=fermionic_transformation.qubit_mapping,
                                        two_qubit_reduction=fermionic_transformation._two_qubit_reduction)
    var_form = UCCSD(num_orbitals=fermionic_transformation.molecule_info['num_orbitals'],
                              num_particles=fermionic_transformation.molecule_info['num_particles'],
                              initial_state=initial_state,
                              qubit_mapping=fermionic_transformation.qubit_mapping,
                              two_qubit_reduction=fermionic_transformation._two_qubit_reduction)
    vqe_solver = VQE(qubit_op,var_form,optimizer,initial_state)
    vqe_solver = vqe_solver.run(QuantumInstance(BasicAer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')))
    
    
    
    calc = GroundStateEigensolver(fermionic_transformation, vqe_solver)
    res = calc.solve(driver)
    vqe_energies.append(res.computed_energies[0])
```
````